# Can I declare type of parameters for sql command? I cannot insert a boolean value, it is being considered a string

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to insert into MySQL DB using Powershell, the input data is from a REST API call. I am using Prepare Statement approach to optimize the inserts, I am having issues while inserting values into a column (let `my_col_bool` ) which is of type `Boolean` (i.e `tinyint(1)`).

The input data received from REST API would assign values to `$myVar1`,`$myVar3`,`$myVar3`.  The values assigned to `$myVar3` would be "true / false", as I am adding these values to command parameter and Executing the query, may be it is considering these values as `String` instead of `Boolean` as I am having an Error.

Approach 1:

```
   $oMYSQLCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(@my_col_string,@my_col_int,@my_col_bool)"
   cmd.Prepare()

   $oMYSQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@my_col_string", "")
   $oMYSQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@my_col_int", "")
   $oMYSQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@my_col_bool", "")    
   
   $oMYSQLCommand.Parameters("@my_col_string").Value = $myVar1
   $oMYSQLCommand.Parameters("@my_col_int").Value = $myVar2
   $oMYSQLCommand.Parameters("@my_col_bool").Value = $myVar3

   $oMYSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() /*Error: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect integer value: 'false' for column 'my_col_bool' at row 1" */
```

Approach 2:

```
$oMYSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@my_col_bool",[System.Data]::$SqlDbType.TinyInt)   /*Error: Unable to find type [System.Data] */
```

Approach 3:

```
$oMYSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@my_col_bool",$SqlDbType.TinyInt)  /*Error: Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2". */
```

Approach 4:

```
        $param_var = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@my_col_bool",$SqlDbType.TinyInt)
        $oMYSQLCommand.Parameters.Add($param_var) | Out-Null 

        $oMYSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()/*Error: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect integer value: 'false' for column 'my_col_bool' at row 1" */
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is update on my approach 3, to make it work `$myVar1` should be bool variable

```
$oMYSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@my_col_bool",$SqlDbType.TinyInt)   
[bool]$myVar3_bool=[boolean]::parse($myVar1)   
$oMYSQLCommand.Parameters("@my_col_bool").Value = $myVar3_bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Every .Net driver tries to have exact same interface as MS SQL Connector has.

MS SQL Example:

```
$sqlCmd = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]::new()

[void]$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param1', [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16]::new(22))

[void]$sqlCmd.Parameters.Add('@param2', [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16])
$sqlCmd.Parameters['@param2'].Value = [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16]::new(22)
```

Reference: [System.Data.SqlTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes)

So usually, the methods are same, you just have to use different namespace inside `[]`.

Note that **some** .Net providers use SQL type system, and some use own type system, which is usually at `[VendorName.something]` namespace.

For example, MySQL [seems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDbType.htm) to use `[MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType]::%typeName%` namespace,

Comment: found something like `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType` but looks like it does not provide `tinyint`

Comment: Try `Byte` type which is signed byte in MySQL .Net drive (I think so because there is also UByte unsigned). Must be same as TinyInt